# Horizontally aligning input fields

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to get an input field, and it's associated submit button on the same horizontal line, but proving to be a challenge.

Here is my code:

```
<form name="prodSearch" action="/products/index.cfm" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="prodKeyword" maxlength="50">
        <input type="image" name="submit" src="/_css/images/but-ok-small.png">
</form>
```

You can view the site at (form is in the header) : http://d620923.u161.fasthit.net/

Basically I either need to nudge the input field up a bit, or the button down a bit.  I've tried everything.. line height, padding, margin, tables etc.. but can't get them to budge.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: did you try using vertical-align property. You can use same height, padding and margin too to ensure both elements are aligned properly.

Comment: It's really unclear what your question is. Are you trying to get two inputs onto the same line (horizontal distribution), or trying to line up two inputs (vertically) which are already on the same line.

Comment: Hi Jpaugh.. I can't see how it is unclear..  as per the questions title, I was trying to align them "Horizontally"... keep in mind this was posted 5 years ago, so likely not on Bootstrap or Google Material.. and field was not aligning directly with button in that one was slightly higher than the other.  Answer below solved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this to your style.

```
#productSearch form input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for textfield:

```
float: left;
```

for the button:

```
margin-top: 2px;
float: right;
```

Comment: A margin in pixels works only for a specific font sizes. The problem is here that the text field's height is measured in ems, while the button's height is in pixels.