# POST parameters in HTML a tag

Tags: jquery, html, django, tags

I'm a little stuck, so I hope you can help me.

I have a page where I want some buttons to be images, but, while I want them in a line (inside de cell of a table), when using `<form>` they get one on top of other.

That's why I want to use the `<a>` tag.

Here's the form I want to submit:

```
<form action="{% url send_img_data %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="param" value="{{ data_img.id }}">
  <input type="image" title="{{ data_img.name }}" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/{{ data_img }}.png" alt="Submit Form" name="image">  
</form>
```

Any idea on how can I do the same but with an `<a>` tag?

**PS:** In the back I'm using Django

Comment: You can look at this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757963/horizontally-aligning-a-input-fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS to re-arrange your `input` tags. Add:

```
input {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Don't use `a` tag to hold form data, data won't get submitted on form submission. Only `input` tags can hold form data.

Answer (score 0):

You should use css property as following:

```
a
{
   display:inline-block; 
}
```

And let me know is it work for you.

P.S. If you are using `<a>` tag as button you should consider to submit your `form` using javascript and ajax call. Because your `<a>` button will not sumbit `form`. So consider about this.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is defin the image of the button on the CSS

```
.buttonStyle {
    border: none;
    background: url('../../../img/image.png');
    height: 17px;
    width: 16px;
    font: 10px/14px Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Arial;
    color: transparent;
    padding: 0 0 0 16px !important;
}
```

Template:

```
<input  id="submit" type="submit" class="buttonStyle"
                                    name="submit">
```